# CustomAttribute with property that is a AttributeTarget property name as string

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, data-annotations

I want to change my `CustomAttribute` usage in this way, I'm using it to refer to the search parameters of an autocomplete dropdown

now:

```
[EntitySearchDropBox(Id="Id",SearchColumns="Name")]
public virtual class MyTarget
```

But i hate strings for defining entity properties and the best solution for me is passing `AttributeTarget` property without writing free strings.

```
[EntitySearchDropBox(Id=MyTarget.Id,SearchColumns=MyTarget.Name)]
public virtual class MyTarget
```

MyTarget example

```
public class MyTarget{
    public int Id    {get; set;}
    public string Name  {get; set;}
    public string otherProperty { get; set; }
    //etc..
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... What's the problem?

Comment: I want to use the Intellisense to fill in data in my attribute, using Attribute Target propeties